# How TCP handle mutiple concurrent requests from same host

Tags: networking, tcp, parallels

Say there is a web server that exposes port 80 with two endpoints, one for returning datasetA, the other for returning datasetB.

I have an application that does multithreading so I might send two requests in parallel, requestA to access datasetA, requestB to access datasetB in parallel
.

Based on my understanding on TCP is:

a TCP connection between two hosts are uniquely identified by the following 5-tuple:

A uniquely identified by the following 5-tuple:

- Protocol (UDP, TCP)
- IP-address of Host A.
- Port number of Host A.
- IP-address of Host B.
- Port number of Host B.

In my case, the ip address and the port number of the source are the same to the server

Will it create confusion for TCP? Say requestA have established three way handshake with the server, and requestA  is sending the request data then request kicks in and send a Syn to the server, wouldn't TCP get confused that " we just agree on sending data each other, why you request to connect with me again"?

Comment: "In my case, the ip address and the port number of the source are the same to the server"—why do you think that would be the case?

Answer (score 2):

Your client process doesn't specify what local TCP port number its connection request will "come from". Its local TCP stack just auto-assigns each such new connection attempt a free port number  from the ephemeral port range (49152 and above). So the TCP connection being set up for the request for datasetB will have a different source port number than the existing TCP connection for datasetA, which is what makes it a different TCP connection.

Even if this is all to and from localhost, it would be two connections:

127.0.0.1:4915**2** <--> 127.0.0.1:80
127.0.0.1:4915**3** <--> 127.0.0.1:80